# JavaScript function in URL field value

Tags: javascript, column, url, spfield, spurl

Is it possible to set the value for the URL field so that when clicked it runs a JavaScript function? I have created a field which stores links to files in SharePoint, but when clicked, the file is opened in read-only mode. I would like to put a JavaScript function call in that field so that it gets executed when the user clicks on it and the file is opened in edit mode.